# Swiping pointer - connecting word game

Tags: java, android

Make custom view to arrange letters and swiping between letters

I'm new to android and want to make something like this :
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yF7im.png)
Draw a circle and arrange letters in it and we can make words by swiping finger between letters.
So this is my code :

```
package com.my.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class CircleView extends View {
    private int circleColor;
    private int borderColor;
    private int borderWidth;
    private ArrayList<String> letters;
    private int letterMargin;

    private Paint circlePaint;
    private Paint borderPaint;
    private Paint textPaint;

    private float touchX;
    private float touchY;
    private Set<String> selectedLetters;
    private String currentWord;
    private OnWordCompleteListener onWordCompleteListener;

    public CircleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CircleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        circleColor = Color.BLUE;
        borderColor = Color.BLACK;
        borderWidth = 5;
        letters = new ArrayList<>();
        letterMargin = 10;

        circlePaint = new Paint();
        circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);

        borderPaint = new Paint();
        borderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(borderWidth);

        textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        textPaint.setTextSize(45);
        textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

        selectedLetters = new HashSet<>();
        currentWord = "";
        onWordCompleteListener = null;
    }

    public void setCircleColor(int color) {
        circleColor = color;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setBorderColor(int color) {
        borderColor = color;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setBorderWidth(int width) {
        borderWidth = width;
        borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(borderWidth);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setLetters(ArrayList<String> letters) {
        this.letters = letters;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setLetterMargin(int margin) {
        letterMargin = margin;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setOnWordCompleteListener(OnWordCompleteListener listener) {
        onWordCompleteListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        int radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

        circlePaint.setColor(circleColor);
        borderPaint.setColor(borderColor);

        canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius, circlePaint);
        canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius - borderWidth / 2, borderPaint);

        if (letters != null && !letters.isEmpty()) {
            int letterCount = letters.size();
            float angle = 360f / letterCount;

            for (int i = 0; i < letterCount; i++) {
                String letter = letters.get(i);
                float textAngle = i * angle - 90;
                float x = (float) (width / 2
                        + (radius - borderWidth - letterMargin) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(textAngle)));
                float y = (float) (height / 2
                        + (radius - borderWidth - letterMargin) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(textAngle)));

                if (selectedLetters.contains(letter)) {
                    textPaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                } else {
                    textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                }

                canvas.drawText(letter, x, y, textPaint);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touchX = event.getX();
            touchY = event.getY();
            handleTouch();
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touchX = event.getX();
            touchY = event.getY();
            handleTouch();
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (onWordCompleteListener != null) {
                onWordCompleteListener.onWordComplete(currentWord);
            }
            clearSelection();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private void handleTouch() {
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        int radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

        float centerX = width / 2;
        float centerY = height / 2;

        double angle = Math.atan2(touchY - centerY, touchX - centerX);
        angle = Math.toDegrees(angle) + 90;
        if (angle < 0) {
            angle += 360;
        }

        int letterCount = letters.size();
        float letterAngle = 360f / letterCount;

        int selectedIndex = (int) (angle / letterAngle);
        if (selectedIndex >= 0 && selectedIndex < letterCount) {
            String selectedLetter = letters.get(selectedIndex);
            if (!selectedLetters.contains(selectedLetter)) {
                selectedLetters.add(selectedLetter);
                currentWord += selectedLetter;
                invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    private void clearSelection() {
        selectedLetters.clear();
        currentWord = "";
        invalidate();
    }

    public interface OnWordCompleteListener {
        void onWordComplete(String word);
    }
}
```

but i don't know how can i draw a line following our finger and each letter.
This is output :
[My sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4E0pZ.jpg)
Can anyone help me find this?

Comment: Pls post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)